# when i am fetching the data of students by city in tkinter it's only show last value

Tags: python, tkinter

As I mention I want to print data of student who's belong from city but in label it only shows one data and terminal shows all the data

I am using for loop to print data

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
# from normalfile import *
window=Tk()
window.geometry("800x500")
window.config(bg="yellow")



varlbl=Label(text="Welcome to Program")
varlbl.pack()

varname=Label(text="name")
varname.pack()

txtname=Entry()
txtname.pack()

varroll=Label(text="RollNo")
varroll.pack()
txtroll=Entry()

txtroll.pack()

varper=Label(text="Percentage")
varper.pack()

txtper=Entry()
txtper.pack()


cityValue=StringVar()

City1=Radiobutton(text="Ahemdabad",value="Ahemdabad",variable=cityValue)
City1.pack()  

City2=Radiobutton(text="Gandhinagar",value="Gandhinagar",variable=cityValue)
City2.pack()  

City3=Radiobutton(text="Surat",value="Surat",variable=cityValue)
City3.pack()  


def Insert():
    name=txtname.get()
    rollno=txtroll.get()
    perc=txtper.get()
    city=cityValue.get()
    f=open("demo.txt","a")
    f.write(f"{name} {rollno} {perc} {city}\n")
    messagebox.showinfo("gui file","Data Saved :")
    f.close()
    
def showData():
    f=open("demo.txt")    
    data=f.read()
    lbl['text']=data
    f.close()
    
def rollno():
    rollno1=txtroll.get()
    f=open("demo.txt","r")    
    for value in f:
        roll=value.split()
        if roll[1]==rollno1:
            rolllbl['text']=value
def City():
    city=cityValue.get()
    fr=open("demo.txt",'r')
    for value in fr:
        citylist=value.split()
        if citylist[3]==city:
            citylbl['text']=value
            print(value)

btn=Button(text="ADD",command=Insert)
btn.pack()

btn2=Button(text="Show",command=showData)
btn2.pack()

btn3=Button(text="Search by rollno",command=rollno)
btn3.pack()

btn4=Button(text="Search by City",command=City)
btn4.pack()

lbl=Label(bg="white")
lbl.pack()

rolllbl=Label(bg="pink")
rolllbl.pack()

citylbl=Label(bg="grey")
citylbl.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

here is text file

```
dhaval 1 72 Gandhinagar
farhan 2 22 Ahemdabad
kinjal 3 72 Surat
dhaval 4 72 Gandhinagar
utsav 5 65 Ahemdabad
uday 6 87 Gandhinagar
piku 7 99.99 Surat
kema 8 59 Ahemdabad
johnbezod 007 99.100 Surat
johnbezod 007 99.100 Surat
```

**expected outcome if selected surat then**

```
kinjal 3 72 Surat

piku 7 99.99 Surat        

johnbezod 007 99.100 Surat

johnbezod 007 99.100 Surat
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting `citylbl['text']=value` each time through the loop. You need to concatenate so you get all the values.

```
def City():
    city=cityValue.get()
    fr=open("demo.txt",'r')
    citylbl['text'] = ''
    for value in fr:
        citylist=value.split()
        if citylist[3]==city:
            citylbl['text'] += value + '\n'
            print(value)
```

Comment: thanks you sir it's workimg now